# AutoCompleteTextView Set Height to Fill Parent

Tags: android, dropdown, autocompletetextview

there I am a newbie to Android Development, and learning it to my own! I just want my AutoCompleteTextView Drop Down height to be set to Fill the Parent.

---

My AutoCompleteTextView View in XML is:

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/countries_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"
    android:ems="10">
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

---

I am also attaching a screenshot that shows the green part of the drop down filling just a part of the parent, but I want it to fill the parent by its height. I don't know if its possible or not? Can somebody figure me out for the possibility?

---

[image: DropDown not filling the parent by its Height]

---

For an extra info I am adding the complete Layout here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/countries_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"
        android:ems="10">
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/revealLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#00FFA9"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textReveal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Hello Reveal!"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_24ssp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add your entire xml code

Comment: Hey you can give fix size like this  `android:dropDownHeight="size"`

Comment: @AJay I tried it also!

Comment: @JavaNerd you have to give int there. `android:dropDownHeight="468dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Set height as match_parent in AutoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/countries_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"
android:ems="10">
```

Comment: if i set the layout_height then the TextView only fills the parent and the layout will be disturb

Comment: that case you have to fill/increase data upto bottom otherwise this is only option to fill screen

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in `android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"` then it will work after API 8 not less to it. Unless you put fixed value like 200dp or 300dp.